# in accordion ,how to toggle between plus and minus icon for all the previous opened tabs?

Tags: javascript, icons, toggle, accordion

in accordion ,how to toggle between plus and minus icon for all the previous opened tabs?

hi.I am new to coding in javascript and I have created a collapse accordion by bootstrap.when i click on each tab , its content will be disappeared and the plus sign changes to minus icon. but the problem happens when one tab or content is opened and once I click on the **another** tab  the icon of previous tab wont change to plus sign although it is toggled to closed state.

This is the code:

````
\<html lang="en"\>

\<head\>
\<meta charset="UTF-8"\>
\<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"\>
\<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"\>
\<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous"\>


    <title>Document</title>

    \</head\>
    ```

    \<body\>
    
    `    <div class="question-container" id="accordion">
        
    `     <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-  target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">   
                <h3>question1</h3>`
            </button>
            <div class="collapse " id="collapseExample" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
                <p>paragraph1</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample-two" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                <h3>question2</h3>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse " id="collapseExample-two" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
                <p>paragraph2</p>
            </div>
        
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample-three" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                <h3>question3</h3>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-three" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
                <p>paragraph3</p>
            </div>
        
        
        
        
        </div>
        
        
        <style>
        .btn.btn-success h3:after {
          content: "\02795"; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
          font-size: 13px;
          color: aliceblue;
          position: absolute;
          left: 0px;
          margin-left: 5px;
        }
        .btn.btn-success.active h3:after {
          content: "\2212";
          font-size: 13px;
          color: aliceblue;
        }
        .btn.btn-success.active {
          border-bottom: none;
          border-radius: 0;
          border-top: none;
          border-left: none;
          border-right: none;
          padding-left: 0px;
          padding-right: 0px;
          padding-bottom: 15px;
          padding-top: 30px;
          width: 100%;
        }
        
        .btn.btn-success.active:hover {
          border-bottom: none;
        }
        
        .btn-success {
          background-color: #0a9e79 !important;
          position: relative;
          right: 0;
        }
        .btn.btn-success {
          border-bottom: 2px dotted #e8f0ee;
          border-radius: 0;
          border-top: none;
          border-left: none;
          border-right: none;
          padding-left: 0px;
          padding-right: 0px;
          padding-bottom: 15px;
          padding-top: 30px;
          width: 100%;
        }
        .btn.btn-success h3 {
          text-align: right;
        }
        .btn.btn-success:hover {
          border-bottom: 2px dotted #e8f0ee;
        }
        
        </style>
        
        <script>
            var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-success");
            var i;
        
            for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                    this.classList.toggle("active");
                });
            }
        </script>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"    integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    \</body\>
    
    \</html\>`
````

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap, why do you make your own accordion instead of using [their pre-made one](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/accordion/)? That don't even need any lines of additional JS to work.